# Sites that show in navigation are not appearing in the Site Content and Structure screen?

Tags: 2007, content-and-structure

I am looking to rearrange the structure of a site to make its secondary page the default page when clicked upon in the navigation, I understand this can be done through the "Site Content and Structure" screen.

When I visit this screen, all other sites and subsites are visible apart from the one I require to change, this site is also not available for public viewing yet, could this be part of it? Is there a way to make this appear within the list? Maybe something i'm missing? I have full control over this part of the site along with full permissions for all sites and subsites.

Many thanks.

Comment: Does it appear in the list of sites when you go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Navigation/Topbar?

Comment: Yes it does, but is displayed with a folder icon, the rest of the sites are displayed with a hierarchy icon.

Comment: The folder icon indicates that that menu item has been manually created in the Navigation/Topbar. When you click on the menu item in the navigation, can you verify that the site is indeed within the same domain?

Comment: Yes it's running off the same url as the rest of the pages in the site and appears just fine when clicked upon in the navigation.